# What happened to the color pallete?

Tags: shaders

Why don't I get the normal color pallette in my material?  what happened?  I've never seen this before.

My color palette is seemingly faulty. I am sure it is not, rather I am surely at fault, but I can not fathom what actions I must take to return my colour palette to its original form.

I have tried clicking many icons in the user interface without any success towards solving my problem.

[image]

Comment: Hey :). This seems to be somewhat similar: [All colors locked in blue hue - can't change hue](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/200479/78972). You can use [this helpful guide](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/173685/78972) to check whether it's a Bug that should be reported :).