# All colors locked in blue hue - can't change hue

Tags: rendering, shaders, eevee-render-engine, color, color-management

Somehow suddenly when I want to edit colors anywhere in my project, be it in the color ramp, or the base or subsurface color of the principled BSDF, or the Bloom color picker of Evee, all the colors seem to be locked in a blue hue. But they render as the color I originally defined them to be.
When I now want to change the hue of one of these colours, it automatically jumps back to the blue hue. Also the color wheel only displays the blue hue.

In the ColorRamp of the screenshot, the right color is actually red and not a dark black. The subsurface color is actually also a saturated, bright red.
[image]

I suspect I did something in the color management tab, that causes this to happen. Here a screenshot of my color management tab:

[image]

That's how the color picker looks now:
[image]

Luckily the colors are more or less as they should be for the final render, but I would still like to tweak some a bit. And it would be nice to know what caused this to happen, so I know what to do next time...

**Edit:** **The rendered image is only in shades of blue too... but in in the rendered view in the viewport it's as it should be.**

Thank you for the help!

Comment: Hey :). This seems to be somewhat similar: [What happened to the color pallete?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/200422/78972). You can use [this helpful guide](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/173685/78972) to check whether it's a Bug that should be reported :).

Comment: Thank you Jachym! I'm not even sure if it is a bug or if I ticked a box or something, that is more technical than I understand, which makes the colors behave differently...

Comment: Well, I couldn't recreate this in any way :). The color picker should show the whole color wheel, not just blue.

Comment: Ok, that's already good to know :)

Answer (score 1):

Ok, because I didn't expect this to be a bug, I didn't go through the usual procedures.

Simply restarting Blender did the job.

sorry for nooby behaviour ;)